# Display product variation description or product short description based on product type in WooCommerce checkout

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product, checkout

This code snippet displays **product short description** at WooCommerce checkout:

```
// Display on cart & checkout pages
function filter_woocommerce_get_item_data( $item_data, $cart_item ) {
    // Product excerpt
    $post_excerpt = get_the_excerpt( $cart_item['product_id'] );
    
    // NOT empty
    if ( ! empty( $post_excerpt ) ) {
        $item_data[] = array(
            'key'     => __( 'Product description', 'woocommerce' ),
            'value'   => $post_excerpt,
            'display' => $post_excerpt,
        );
    }
    
    return $item_data;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_item_data', 'filter_woocommerce_get_item_data', 10, 2 );
```

The issue is that a variable product can only have 1 product short description, so all of the product variations have the same exact description.

Is it possible to modify this code snippet to display **product variation description** instead of **product short description** for variable products?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To display product variation description instead of product short description for variable products, you can use:

```php
// Display on cart & checkout pages
function filter_woocommerce_get_item_data( $item_data, $cart_item ) {   
    // Compare
    if ( $cart_item['data']->get_type() == 'variation' ) {
        // Get the variable product description
        $description = $cart_item['data']->get_description();
    } else {    
        // Get product excerpt
        $description = get_the_excerpt( $cart_item['product_id'] );
    }       
        
    // Isset & NOT empty
    if ( isset ( $description ) && ! empty( $description ) ) {
        $item_data[] = array(
            'key'     => __( 'Description', 'woocommerce' ),
            'value'   => $description,
            'display' => $description,
        );
    }
    
    return $item_data;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_item_data', 'filter_woocommerce_get_item_data', 10, 2 );
```